# Is there anything that can be done when a OP changes a marked answer to an unrelated one?

Tags: discussion, comments, specific-question, specific-answer

On this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662591/replacing-strings-in-multiple-text-files-using-regular-expressions-on-vb-net/38853187?noredirect=1#comment65118983_38853187) I answered it the best I could and believe  I answered their original question. The OP then asked a question on how to implement a progress bar into their program in the comments of my answer, which I deemed to  be a different question to the original problem. So referred to them to do some research into progress bars and ask a new question if stuck and mark this as answered, which the OP did mark as answered.

I later saw that another user had read this and provided another answer to do with progress bars. Which I commented on saying on other ways to do it and so on. But it seems the OP then marked this new answer as answered, meaning I lost reputation for this. I'm not bothered if the OP  believed that my answer didn't answer there question, but I think I did and in the comment thread you can see it has.

But the new answer doesn't answer the original question posted, it answers a new problem that was left in a comments thread after the original problem was answered in my answer. So my question is, is there anything that can be done for when an already marked answer has been changed to another answer that is not related to the original question? Is this common on stack overflow and if so are there ways of tackling this issue?

Comment: That one just leads me on a trail of more duplicated answers

Comment: It's more to do with the OP changing the answer to another user's answer to a new question inside my answer's comment thread

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName no, it is not. And could you pretty, pretty please stop robo-reviewing the queues based on question titles for once?

Comment: @S.L.Barth I don't see how that relates at all to my question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well congratulations, you've found a [help vampire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6119995/tamal-banerjee?tab=questions) who consistently turns their questions into [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) due to a lack of experience and a misunderstanding of how this site works.

One telltale of this behavior is that in each of their questions, at least one answer has more than a few comments of theirs, asking more and more questions that deviate from the original problem as the answer(er) helped them somewhat further with their program.

Blame's on you, you shouldn't answer additional questions that are asked in comments. If a question seems to derail into chameleon behavior, point that out and stop answering their additional questions in comments.

But really, other than ask nicely and explain to them in a comment that this is not what they're supposed to do, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Well when the question changed to helping something that what i deemed completely different from the original problem, I did tell them to research it. With the other answer, I thought because mine was already answered, i would help with it. but then i saw they changed marked answer. Oh well, 1st time this has happened to me. I'll be more careful next time. The chameleon question was interesting read. Thanks for the answer

Comment: This is all true, except that the blame isn't really on the person who attempted to answer in good faith. It is not our job to go back through an asker's past questions and assess their behavior. In fact, that would be a really *bad* thing to start doing. Each question should stand alone and be answered in good faith. If it turns into a help vampire/chameleon question situation, then you bow out. It's not your fault. (This is distinct from answering *obvious garbage*, where the fault really is on both the asker and answerer.)

Comment: @Cody agreed, edited.